# indicate the iface to use using generics in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I'm unsure what's the correct this title for that, but this is what I want to do:

I have a License system that is based on dongle (usb stick) containing features. And now they added some elements that use file based licensing (where they store the features)

So I want :

```
public iface ILicensesManager
      bool CheckFeature(int)




public class DongleController : ILicensesManager
     CheckFeature(int f)
         return CheckForTheIdInTheUSBThingy(f);

public class FileBasedLicenseController : ILicensesManager
    CheckFeature(int f)
         return WhateverIsNeeededToCheckInTheFile(f)
```

Then I have Licenses that stipulate the ID to be search and the method to be used. Right now I pass it through constructor

```
public virtual class License
       private ILincesesManager Checker;
       protected int FeatureID

       public License(ILincesesManager)
       public bool Check()
             CheckFeature(FeatureID);




public class ArmLicense : License
       public License() : base {
          FeatureID = 105;
       }


public class LegLicense: License
       public License() : base {
          FeatureID = 107;
       }


public class ElbowLicensse: License
       public License() : base {
          FeatureID = 202;
       }
```

So one can create a license like this:

```
License arm = new ArmLicense(DongleChecker))
License leg = new LegLicense(FileBasedLicense)
```

and then check them like

```
bool Ok = arm.Check();
bool Ok = leg.Check();
```

What I'd like to do is to be able to create them like :

```
License arm = new ArmLicense<DongleChecker>();
```

How to do that ?? Is that a good a approach at all ?

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense to me. What is `DongleChecker` for example?

Comment: You probably want "Generic Constraints": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters

Comment: @DavidG a dongle is a usb device for licensing software. once plugged you can use an API to ask what features are available. We use it to charge our clients. https://www.google.com/search?q=security+dongle&sxsrf=ALeKk03XaqPJXPERM8cpqk2FHBAM012NuQ:1589461350987&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjawtb5tLPpAhXTBWMBHfiFAkoQ_AUoAXoECBIQAw&biw=1920&bih=979

Comment: I know what a dongle is, I wanted to know what DongleChecker is. It seems you're just asking if generics is the right thing to do and I have no way to tell. I would guess it's not.

Comment: I have mixed licenses, some of them are checked against a dongle, some of them against a file some against a server. I want a way to call License.Check and internally it will call the class that was selected for him (file, dongle or others=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class License<TMANAGER> 
    where TMANAGER: ILicensesManager 
{
    public License(TMANAGER licenseManager)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class ArmLicense<TMANAGER> : License<TMANAGER> 
    where TMANAGER: ILicensesManager 
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: how do I call methods from the TMANAGER, do I have to make a new TMANAGER?

Comment: You pass an instance ans assign it to a variable. When needed you call your iface method on previously declared and assigned variable